# How can i convert DatePicker object to datestring

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, antd

I am using antd. I have a form that i want to send instead of DatePicker Object i want only the string but i don't know how to get the string from the Object.

I don't have any state or value to change.

Object:

```
_d: Date Mon Oct 26 2020 13:03:25 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
​​_isAMomentObject: true
```

I find this but i am not sure if is the best way to do.

```
    console.log(date._d.toISOString())
```

Results: (and just take only the date)

```
2020-01-01T11:26:21.765Z
```

Do you know if is a better solution for this just to take 2020-01-01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Moment Js.

```
moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```